# How can I make a repeat until loop?

Tags: python, while-loop

complete newbie here. I wanted to make the user enter a name that matches one of the names in the dictionary, else the program asks again until a correct name is entered. Here's the code:

```
class Yakuza:
    def __init__(self, name, clan):
        self.name = name
        self.clan = clan
        
    def present(self):
        print(f"Hello! I am {self.name} from the {self.clan} clan!")
        
user1 = Yakuza("Kiryu", "Dojima")
user2 = Yakuza("Nishikiyama", "Dojima")

Startup = input("Welcome to Yakuza 0! Press Enter to start.")

character_dictionary = {"Kiryu" : "Dojima Clan",
                        "Nishikiyama" : "Dojima Clan"}
print(character_dictionary)

character_select = input("Select your character: ")

while character_select in character_dictionary:

    if character_select == "Kiryu":
        user1.present()
            
    elif character_select == "Nishikiyama":
        user2.present()
    
    else:
        print("This character is not available. Try again")
```

I expected the loop to work until a correct name is entered but it keeps going forever. Also, does it matter whether the character_select input is in or out of the while loop?

Comment: How do you expect `character_select` to change inside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Yakuza:
    def __init__(self, name, clan):  # Fixed __init__ typo here
        self.name = name
        self.clan = clan

    def present(self):
        print(f"Hello! I am {self.name} from the {self.clan} clan!")
    
user1 = Yakuza("Kiryu", "Dojima")
user2 = Yakuza("Nishikiyama", "Dojima")

Startup = input("Welcome to Yakuza 0! Press Enter to start.")

character_dictionary = {"Kiryu": "Dojima Clan", "Nishikiyama": "Dojima Clan"}
print(character_dictionary)

while True:  # Changed the condition here
    character_select = input("Select your character: ")  # Moved inside the loop
    if character_select in character_dictionary:
        if character_select == "Kiryu":
            user1.present()
            break  # Exit the loop after successful execution
        elif character_select == "Nishikiyama":
            user2.present()
            break  # Exit the loop after successful execution
    else:
        print("This character is not available. Try again.")
```

Comment: Probably you should explain your code.

Answer (score 1):

The general form of a repeat-until loop is

```
while True:
    ...

    if <condition>:
        break
```

Instead of checking the condition at the *top* of the loop (where it can fail before the body is entered), we loop "forever" and only check the condition at the *end* of the loop (the `if` statement is the last statement in the body), explicitly exiting the loop if the condition is true.